# Jetpack compose webview fails to show pages randomly

Tags: android, html, webview, android-jetpack-compose

I have a WebView in an android app. Sometimes, the page in the webview does not show. This happens randomly: for the same page, it sometimes appears, sometimes does not. Despite the page not showing, a blank area occupies the appropriate amount of space (I know because below the webview there are other controls). The curious thing is that if I inspect the webview with `chrome://inspect`, the page is there and shows up correctly.

When the problem happens, if I perform small changes in the html through the DevTools, the same effect persists: the new page appears in the DevTools view but, in the device, a blank space is shown with the area that should be occupied by the new page. The page only shows when I change something in the html/css that makes it resize a lot.

The app uses Jetpack Compose and uses `WebView` by means of `AndroidView`. When the problem happens, the following backtrace appears **sometimes** in logcat:

```
2021-02-16 16:08:34.866 9683-9698/... E/System: Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
2021-02-16 16:08:34.909 9683-9698/... E/System: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Warning: Router objects should be explicitly closed when no longer required otherwise you may leak handles.
        at w4.finalize(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:4)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:289)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:276)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:137)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
     Caused by: java.lang.Exception: AutocloseableRouter allocated at:
        at w4.<init>(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:4)
        at vu.<init>(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:8)
        at org.chromium.content.browser.framehost.RenderFrameHostImpl.<init>(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:10)
        at org.chromium.content.browser.framehost.RenderFrameHostImpl.create(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:1)
        at J.N.MZAK3_Tx(Native Method)
        at org.chromium.content.browser.webcontents.WebContentsImpl.E0(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:3)
        at qP.renderFrameDeleted(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:2)
        at org.chromium.content.browser.webcontents.WebContentsObserverProxy.renderFrameDeleted(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:2)
        at J.N.MQGusfGb(Native Method)
        at v5.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:2)
        at ze.handleMessage(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:21)
        at Be.a(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:3)
        at Be.<init>(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:3)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.M(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:88)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.L(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:2)
        at org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.<init>(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:67)
        at L60.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:9)
        at L80.b(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:3)
        at J80.run(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:1)
        at org.chromium.base.task.PostTask.c(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:3)
        at L80.a(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:3)
        at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-432415233:77)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:429)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:353)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:336)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:323)
        at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:313)
        (my invocation)
```

I am using WebView as follows:

```
@Composable
fun WebViewView(
    html: String,
    baseUrl: String? = null
) {
    AndroidView({ context ->

        val webView = WebView(context)

        // configure webview

        webview
    })
}
```

What can be the cause of this?